# QGIS - How to change label placement mode from 'Around Point' to 'Offset From Point' using Python

Tags: pyqgis, labeling

I am trying to create labels for 3 separate measurements, which I intend to offset in the label placement options so that the text appears above, centered and below a given point. The problem I am encountering though, is that I can't get QGIS to change the label placement mode from 'Around Point' to 'Offset from Point'.

My original code looked like this:

```
    pal_layer = QgsPalLayerSettings()
    pal_layer.isExpression = True
    pal_layer.fieldName ="""round("%s" * 1.09361)"""  % (fieldName)

    pal_layer.enabled = True
    pal_layer.placement = 1
    pal_layer.quadOffset = 1
    pal_layer.xOffset = 0
    pal_layer.yOffset = offsetY
```

I would expect *pal_layer.placement* to set the placement mode to 'Offset from Point' , however, in the current version of QGIS I am running, both *pal_layer.placement* and *pal_layer.quadOffset* expect an enum and not an integer. This has confused me, as previous forum posts on a similar topic would suggest that this code should work fine. I have looked at the documentation for *Class: QgsPalLayerSettings* and I can see that *QgsPalLayerSettings.**P**lacement* uses an integer but *QgsPalLayerSettings.**p**lacement* does not. I'm not sure if that could be causing an issue? Regardless, I am mainly interested in how to set the label placement mode to 'Offset from Point' via Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the QgsPalLayerSettings.placement field changed from `int` to `enum` in QGIS version 3.26.

If you were using an earlier version, what you have should work (I was able to change placements in 3.22 using similar code to yours).

For versions >= 3.26, you should just be able to update your code with:

`pal_layer.placement = Qgis.LabelPlacement.OverPoint`

Reference: [Qgis.LabelPlacement API reference](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgis.html#a3acc05d5f279798221dd3f0f5ceae573)

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly!